# Find the IMEI number of lost Android phone

Tags: google-account, imei

It used to be possible to find the IMEI number of a device from [Google Dashboard](https://myaccount.google.com/dashboard?pli=1). However, I couldn't find it now. Majority of the answers I find on the internet refers me to this method but it doesn't work.

Is it possible to find the IMEI number of a lost Android phone using Google Dashboard? If yes, then how?

Comment: Probably the easiest way is to look at the box the phone came in, or the receipt, as it'll be printed on both. That relies on you having kept either, though.

Comment: I have not kept that. :(  Previously I was able to track using google dashboard. Not able this time.

Comment: Where did you buy the phone from? You can contact them. IMEI numbers are usually written on the receipts and the seller is supposed to keep a copy or digital records of the receipt.

Comment: @SarpSTA bought it on foreign country. so could not do what you have mentioned.

Comment: If you cannot get it from your carrier, and you don't have the box or receipt with the IMEI number on it, you are basically out of luck. A few years ago Google made some changes and you cannot see the IMEI of the device connected to your account, unless you purchased it through the Play Store. I would make this an answer but I cannot find the reference link.

Comment: Did you contact your carrier and see if they have it?

Comment: You might also be able to contact Google support and ask for the IMEI number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, as of July 2019, you can still get your IMEI number from the dashboard. Just go to the ["Find your  device"](https://myaccount.google.com/find-your-phone-guide) page and select your device. Then in the upper left corner, the name of your device will appear with an (i) icon next to it. Click on that and it tells you IMEI number.

[image: d b]

Comment: Still works as of 8/29/2018.

Comment: This gave me a diff imei number compared to one on the phone box

Answer (score 5):

*Not a way to find it , but to document that it's not possible from Google Dashboard anymore*

> Is it possible to find the IMEI number of a lost Android phone using Google Dashboard?

**Unfortunately NO**

Google removed this feature for reasons best known to them. From [Google Support](https://support.google.com/mail/forum/AAAAK7un8RU2cl1n0crK8U/?hl=en), see what 
*NoGoodDeed* says

> As catzrule states, Google has was removed IMEI information from the new dashboard view.
>
> Google is considering where and if it might be appropriate to re-surface that info. 
>   You can leave  [Feedback](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6142372)
>   about this with Gmail.

This is the latest official source (October last year) I could find, so there is no way out unless you have the box or bill mentioning IMEI.

Other possibilities

- If you synced to [itunes](http://trendblog.net/how-to-find-imei-android-ios-without-phone/) as claimed here ( I can't confirm)
- Another *very* long shot is if you had installed a paid app that is single device use and is linked to your IMEI number (I have a call recorder app that does this and everytime I change my device , need to mail them with new IMEI number, so end up having a record)
- As Bochur mentioned in comments (thanks), asking Telco is another possibility

I wish Google would reintroduce this

**Edit** Things that didn't help

- Chatting with Google help from Play Store options - they were totally clueless and couldn't direct me to somebody who can help
- Downloading data from [Google Dashboard](https://myaccount.google.com/dashboard?pli=1). Combed but to no avail. Only interesting thing is that you can see your Google ID here

Comment: This is just not true. See the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

I have good news, I was able to find my Andriod Device using Google Dashboard by going to the Find My Device page once I logged in.
Just press the i by the name of your device.
Here is a print screen in case I am not clear. 
Hope it helps.
[image: Print Screen]

Comment: Direct link: https://www.google.com/android/find

Answer (score 0):

Yes goto find my phone click on the lost device and click on locate then on the screen of the locate device click on the (!) It will tell you the imei #